# CSS - How to select elements with same class inside div without nth-child

Tags: css

Is it possible to select elements with the same class inside a specific div element without using nth-child ?
I'm working on a simple web crawler that has completed already but the issue that I'm struggling is that I can't use a css selector like :nth-child , anyway currently I'v faced a html structure in a website trying to get its content ( with respect to its own policies ) , the structure is as follows :

```
<div class="w700">
    <p class="line"><!--some content here --></p>
    <p class="line"><!--some content here --></p>
    <p class="line"><!--some content here --></p>
    <p class="line"><!--some content here --></p>
    <p class="line"><!--some content here --></p>
    <p class="line"><!--some content here --></p>
    <p class="line"><!--some content here --></p>
    <p class="line"><!--some content here --></p>
</div>
```

My problem is that I want to select ( via CSS ) for example the 7th or 8th or any other item of the p elements inside the mentioned div.w700 without using of :nth-child.

Comment: ***Why*** can't you use `:nth-child`, which is the correct tool for the job? Because (unlike your example) only some of the child elements will have the target `line` class?

Comment: Define "select." You've said "with CSS", but you've tagged jQuery in the question as well. Are you looking for a CSS selector, specifically, or a way to select these elements in jQuery (which means there are more options)?

Comment: `:nth-of-type` is also out of the question?

Comment: Are you using Javascript/jQuery for this web crawler?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a very active place. When you post a question, please *stick around* for a couple of minutes to answer queries like the above.

Comment: thank you guys for commenting out my question, actually I don't use jquery in the regard

Comment: @HosseinBahrami: Okay, so I've removed the irrelevant [tag:jquery] for you then (also the irrelevant [tag:html]). **Again**: Why don't you want to use the correct tool for this (`:nth-child`)?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder   I just can't imagine why a web crawler would need to style the appearance of the page .... May be we are talking about selecting the elements in JS instead of jQuery ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder actually the engine the I'v written for the crawler is for a few years ago. Currently I have a config file containing an array that inside this array every element that required to be fetched from html page is defined with their css selector . I searched for an approach to without having to manipulate the core can handle such a problem because this is only one single url that I'm encountering such issue

Comment: @T.J.Crowder by take advantage of your comments and search on the Web and also some personal efforts on the code finally I found out that there is no tricky way to handle this issue so I decided to manipulate the crawler core codes to getting know about css selectors that when creating the scraper a few years ago they didn't exist in css world.  Anyway thank you guys to take time to my issue

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my own problem so share it may be can help others that read this post in the future.

Previously I have used simple_html_dom php class to getting html element contents via css selectors and as I saw during research I found out it is not capable to handle complicated css selectors like :nth-child and because of this I have to manipulate the crawler codes for using more sophisticated library like the one mentioned here : https:// github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom

Hope this can help someone else

Answer (score -3):

There is no way to select an element using only CSS in the way that you want to without using nth-child or a similar selector. You could give the elements that you want to select another class that gives only specific elements the desired properties.

I am not sure what exactly your question is asking for, but I hope this answers it.

Comment: Anyway thanks for answering but the html page doesn't belong to me to edit it . It's a page that intended to be crawled

Comment: On principle, I will not delete my answer. I answered the question to the best of my ability, given the information provided at the time. I wasn't _exactly_ sure what his question was asking for, but I thought I had the general idea, which is why I tried to help answer it.